# getBlock() is empty. How to debug?

Tags: layout, blocks

I'm working with the Aheadworks Mobile theme and experience a strange issue. If I add a product to cart and open the cart (without page refresh) I just see an empty cart. Only after I refresh the page I see the just added product but it never updates the product via Ajax. However, I tracked down the issue to line #55 in AW/Mobile2/controllers/CartController.php

```
$cartBlock = $layout->getBlock('checkout.cart');
```

This is empty! But I'm stuck here and don't know how to debug this further. Any ideas?

Please find complete function below:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class AW_Mobile2_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    protected function _ajaxResponse($result = array())
    {
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
    return;
}

public function addAction()
{
    Mage::register('_no_redirect_flag', true, true);
    parent::addAction();
    $response = array(
        'top_cart_qty' => (int)Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty(),
        'message_box'  => '',
        'cart'         => ''
    );
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $messageBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/messages');
    $messageBlock->addMessages(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getMessages(true));
    $response['message_box'] = $messageBlock->getGroupedHtml();
    try {
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('default');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $cartBlock = $layout->getBlock('checkout.cart');
        if ($cartBlock) {
            $response['cart'] = $cartBlock->toHtml();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    Mage::log(print_r($response,true),true,"addtocart.log");
    $this->_ajaxResponse($response);
}
...
```

The log file says

```
2015-12-18T12:28:27+00:00 ALERT (1): Array
(
    [top_cart_qty] => 1
    [message_box] => <ul class="messages"><li class="success-msg"><ul><li><span>Red Taiko Shirt was added to your shopping cart.</span></li></ul></li></ul>
    [cart] => 
)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look add your modules layout-handles.

The block `checkout.cart` isn't defined under the `default` handle anywhere:

It is defined like that `checkout_cart_index` handle in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
...
</checkout_cart_index>
```

So you have to make sure, that you define the cart block in your modules layout file in the handle `aw_mobile2_cart_add`-handle or under `default`-handle.

Comment: By the way: I think one of the nicest way of Debugging Magento is xdebug (http://xdebug.org/).

It is relatively easy to setup and after installation you can just put a breakpoint and see whats up in the code on this point of request processing.

I recently wrote an article for the installation and usage of xdebug under Linux and PHPStorm. It can be found here: https://www.ask-sheldon.com/php-xdebug/

Answer (score 2):

***checkout.cart*** is block  which *`does not exits`* at **`checkout_cart_add`** handler.That reason you **does not get it  content**. As per as , default magento this block is element of [checkout cart page](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L65)

***For your case,you need call this block at  checkout_cart_add handler by adding code***  layout file`(local.xml or checkout.xml)` .

```
<checkout_cart_add>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </checkout_cart_add>
```